# Unable to install hmmlearn in Python 3

Tags: python, pycharm, hmmlearn

> Failed building wheel for hmmlearn
>   Command "C:\Users\Akash\PycharmProjects\hello\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c
>   "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hmmlearn\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z6k7p8b8\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Akash\PycharmProjects\hello\venv\include\site\python3.6\hmmlearn"
>   failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hmmlearn\

this is the error showing in cmd and in pycharm also. 
i found that Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 14 is required

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, asking me for Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 14 Build tools, I've tried every possible solution that I saw on `Stackoverflow` and `github`.
The only fix that worked for me is using the `.whl` file in [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#hmmlearn](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#hmmlearn) and more importantly using a 32-bit version of the `whl` file **(I just realized i was using 32bit Python3.6 while in a 64bit Win10 OS)**

In the specific `.venv` folder, activate the environment and type:

```
pip install <yourdir>/hmmlearn‑0.2.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
```

Comment: it worked for me.
the only difference is that I chose hmmlearn‑0.2.4‑cp38‑cp**38**‑win32.whl cause I m using python 3.8.x

Comment: what is the alternative for mac m1

Comment: @afsara_ben Have a look at https://pypi.org/project/hmmlearn/#files and find macosx distribution

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to fix problems with packages that need Microsoft Build tools:

1) Using the Anaconda package for Python. If your Python package was shipped with Anaconda, then you just need `conda install hmmlearn`. Personally, all package build errors are fixed for me using this.

2) If you have a standalone installation of Python, then follow the steps below to fix:

a) For Python 3.5, 3.6: Download and Install [Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

b) On the Visual Studio Download page, scroll down and select Tools for Visual Studio 2017. Click on the Download button for `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017`.

c) Restart your computer and try installing hmmlearn with `pip install hmmlearn`.

3) In some cases, where package build errors persist, you can consider building the package using [wheels](https://github.com/superbobry/hmmlearn-wheels).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Command "c:\users\akash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Akash\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cl08vebc\\hmmlearn\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w9shcj_f\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cl08vebc\hmmlearn\     this is problem now

Answer (score 2):

run anaconda prompt as administrator and try the following command "conda install -c conda-forge hmmlearn", that installs the package from another channel, or try any other channel from the link: 
https://anaconda.org/search?q=hmmlearn

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Windows 10. The only channel and subsequent command that worked for me was conda-forge:

`conda install -c conda-forge hmmlearn`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue - another source for the package which I wanted to install did it for me.
For example 'conda install hmmlearn' would cause the issue above.
But after checking anaconda.org for packages, I found the command
'conda install -c omnia hmmlearn'
which solved the situation for me without any further Microsoft Visual C++ installation or action...
Best,
Lania

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for python 3.7.
Downloading the wheel file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#hmmlearn fixed the issue for me.

I downloaded the hmmlearn‑0.2.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl (Since mine is a 64bit machine with python 3)

The github issue and fix for this can be found here https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/issues/289